# How to find the point pairs in two point lists with min distance in a efficent way?

Tags: python, math

```
pointListA = [(13,45),(33,78),...,(360,240)]
pointListB = [(20,36),(47,32),...,(265,322)]
```

The length of pointListA and pointListB is almost 5000 or more.My task is to find the the point in pointListB for each point in pointListA,so that the two points have the min distance between each other.
My question is to find a efficent way to complete this task.I already tried some method such as traverse the two lists both,but it's too slow.So,is there any suggestion for me?

Edit1:
I am so sorry about my descibe in the title just now.Now I modify it to "How to find the point pairs in two point lists with min distance in a efficent way"
Actually, I want a result like this.

```
minDistansceList = [((13,45),(a point in pointListB)),((33,78),(a point in pointListB)).....((360,240),(a point in pointListB))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an optimization you can exploit the fact that you have found the closest point if you have found a point at distance 0, and exploit the fact that a point which minimizes squared distant minimizes distance:

```
def sdist(p,q):
    return (p[0]-q[0])**2 + (p[1]-q[1])**2

def closestPoint(p,points):
    candidate = points[0]
    currentMin = sdist(p,candidate)
    for q in points[1:]:
        d = sdist(p,q)
        if d == 0: return q
        if d < currentMin:
            currentMin = d
            candidate = q
    return candidate

def closestPoints(pointsA,pointsB):
    return [(p,closestPoint(p,pointsB)) for p in pointsA]
```

To test it:

```
from random import randint

ListA = [(randint(0,1000),randint(0,1000)) for i in range(5000)]
ListB = [(randint(0,1000),randint(0,1000)) for i in range(5000)]
```

Then

```
pairs = closestPoints(ListA,ListB)
```

takes about 18 seconds on my 2-year old laptop

Comment: it takes about 8seconds on my computer,that's perfect

Comment: @Elivis The problem is called the *Nearest neighbor search*. At the cost of preprocessing the `pointListB` you should be able to get it down to `O(n*log(n))` rather than `O(n^2)`. The preprocessing appears to be nontrivial and it might not be worth it, but if this proves to be a bottle neck you might want to look into more sophisticated algorithms (such as those that use a k-d tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree ).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but you might be able to do this efficiently by taking the [diagonal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) from the matrix resulting from using the [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist 'euclidean'](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) results thus:

```
#!/bin/python
import numpy as np
from scip.spatial.distance import cdist

pointListB = [(20,36),(47,32),(265,322)]
pointListA = [(13,45),(33,78),(360,240)]
A = np.array(pointListA)
B = np.array(pointListB)
distances = np.diagonal(cdist(A, B, 'euclidean'))
# Minimum distance:
min_dist = np.min(distances)
```

The reason we're taking the diagonal is because `cdist` returns a matrix of distances from every point in A to every point in B.  My concern is that this will be generating AxB intermediary results to extract a vector of len(A) results.  But it will be vectorized operations in NumPy's low level (compiled, binary) code and possibly taking advantage of your CPU's own vector instruction set extensions (SSE on x86, for example).

I suspect that there's some way to eliminate that extra computation, but I don't know enough NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to take two points from each list with the same index, you can `zip` two lists. If you mean the minimum distance between any point chosen from A and B, then you should take the cartesian product of those two lists using `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import starmap, product
>>> from math import sqrt, pow

>>> def distance(p1, p2):
...     return sqrt(pow(p2[1] - p1[1], 2) + pow(p2[0] - p1[0], 2))

>>> pointListA = [(13,45), (33,78), (360,240)]
>>> pointListB = [(20,36), (47,32), (265,322)]

>>> min(starmap(distance, product(pointListA, pointListB)))
11.40175425099138
```

After your update:

```
>>> sorted(product(pointListA, pointListB), key=lambda t: distance(t[0], t[1]))
>>> [((13, 45), (20, 36)), ((13, 45), (47, 32)), ((33, 78), (20, 36)), ...]
```

Comment: You don't need to take the sqrt since you are minimising

Comment: Yeah it was before I thought the OP wanted to see the minimum distance, not the list of pairs ordered by min distance.

Comment: I mean the minimum distance between any point chosen from A and B

Answer (score 1):

you can use the tuples as keys for a dictionary populated by the distances and then pull the min from that.

```
pointListA = ((0,1),(1,2),(3,4),(2,2))
pointListB = ((0,1),(1,2),(3,4),(2,2))
dists = {}
for p0 in pointListA:
    dists[p0] = {}
    for p1 in pointListB:
         d = 0
         for k in [0,1]:
             d += (p0[k]-p1[k])**2
         dists[p0][p1] = d**0.5

minDistPairs = tuple([(k,min(dists[k], key=dists[k].get)) for k in dists])
print minDistPairs
```

Comment: I am sorry about my descride in the title just now.Now, I updated my question.So,is there any idea about this question

Comment: that's not my opreation,I will give u a up:-)

Comment: yeah I forgot to use min({},{}.get) for the min key fetch... sry about that, I should have tested better...

Comment: And one more question, the length of two lists is beyond 5000,I just test the code in my computer with intel i7 core,it need 23s to complete the caculation,is there any way to make it more efficient?

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `str(pointListA/pointlistB) % str(pointListA/pointListB)`